# how to call a number from a url

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making an affiliate program where I count a number of clicks based on this link fridgeblasteraffiliate.freeiz.com/affiliate/?numberherebasedonid but I have this

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("redacted", "redacted", "redacted", 
"redacted");
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 session_start();
  $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $sql = "SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='$ID'";
 $add = 1;
 $ID = strpos($url, needle)
 ?>
```

but as you can see I can't figure out how to call the number in the url to count the clicks

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but you should put `session_start()` right under your opening php tag. You'll save  yourself a lot of hassle down the road if you do that.

Comment: Read up on the `$_GET`-super global: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php. Passing params in the url like that is commonly known as a "query string". Btw, you're currently defining the variable `$ID` _after_ you're trying to use it. It needs to be defined _before_. Also, if the ID is numeric, make sure to cast it as an integer before using it in your db-query, or use prepared statements. Otherwise, you're wide open for SQL injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a GET variable. Try the following URL:

```
fridgeblasteraffiliate.freeiz.com/affiliate/?id=numberherebasedonid
```

Then use `$_GET['id']` in your script to access the value.

```
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='$_GET['id']'";
```

Please note, though, that this code is [vulnerable to SQL injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) As Magnus Eriksson noted in the comments, you can negate this by either typecasting `$_GET['id']` to the int type, or by using prepared statements:

Casting:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='$id'";
```

Prepared statements:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID=?');
$statement->bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: @Daniel for creating the link and number should this work  <div class="link">
      http://fridgeblasteraffiliate.freeiz.com/affiliate?id<?php echo "$_SESSION['ID']";?>
     </div>

Comment: Don't forget the equals (=) sign. `/affiliate/?id=`

Comment: @JonathanConnery If you just want to add a click on that post in the DB, you can updated it directly. You don''t need to select it first. Just do `UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE ID=?`.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for helping me strengthen it but my real question was how do I get the number from the url to add it to the database of clicks

Comment: Magnus already gave you the query. You don't really need to select it, just update it. Just use that query instead

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so this should work? <?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id2278622_jonny", "Fencing1", "id2278622_affiliate");
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
 }
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='$id'";
$add = 1;
"UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE ID='$id'";
?>

Comment: No. First off, remove the "SELECT"-query and the `$add = 1`. Your update query is currently just a string that you don't assign to any variable or anything. You can probably also remove the `$url`-line since you don't need to parse out the ID anymore. Btw, you should also have `if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { die('Invalid id'); }` in the line under `session_start();` to make sure that the parameter is set and correct to begin with.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I got rid of the SELECT and it turned all yellow so i think it was an error

Comment: @JonathanConnery This is very basic PHP syntax. I would recommend going through some PHP-tutorials.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson whenever I load it up the clicks out as You have gotten: SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='1' Clicks!